# what is the hotkey to move to a particular desktop out of all the desktops

Tags: desktop

I know i can use 3 swipe left and right to move to the previous or next desktop, but I think it would be more helpful to have a hotkey to do it and not just moving previously or next, but rather to a particular one.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open System Preferences
2. Select "Keyboard" under "the Hardware" section
3. Select the "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab
4. Select "Mission Control" from the left table
5. Expand the "Mission Control" section

Once there you can see, set, and enable shortcuts to individual Mission Control screens.

[image: screenshot]